# Javascript inheritance using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, design-patterns, prototype

I'm want to use my Parent's class methods in my child class.
In classical OOP, you would simply extend your child class to make use of your parents' functionality, is this possible using prototype?

Here is my file structure:

Parent.js

```
var Parent = function(){
    this.add = function(num) {
        return num + 1;
    };
};

module.exports = Parent;
```

Child.js

```
var Parent = require("./parent.js"),
    util = require("util");

var Child = function() {

    this.sum = function(num) {
        // I want to be able to use Parent.add() without instantiating inside the class 
        // like this:
        console.log(add(num));
    };
};

util.inherits(Child, Parent);

module.exports = Child;
```

program.js

```
var child = require("./child.js");

var Calculator = new child();

Calculator.sum(1);
```

Obviously, `add()` is undefined here.
I've tried using [util.inherits](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) but it I'm not sure it's the right approach.

I'd also like to ask if this is a good design pattern in JavaScript in general, considering I'd like to have multiple child classes inheriting from my parent?

Comment: You have to write it as `this.add(num)`.

Comment: And also you have to do `Parent.call(this)` in the `Child` constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

First, as mentioned in the comments by @Pointy, the `add` method in Child.js should be qualified with `this.`. This is because using `add` will resolve it to the root scope (`window` in browsers).

Second, you are binding the `add` method in `Parent` to each particular instance independently, by using `this.add = function(...){...}`. Bind it to the `Parent` prototype and you'll get what you want.

```
var Parent = function() {}
Parent.prototype.add = function(num) { return num + 1; }
```

The function `Parent.prototype.add` will be inferred to all instances of `Parent` and its derived objects.